# Export WordPress Nav Menus

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have a WP 3.0 site running locally that has an epic menu of about 100 items, I need to export it so I can use it on the live site. But from what I can tell the Export function in WordPress doesn't back up your menus. How can I do it?

Comment: I'm guessing it's probably gonna require a bit of SQL. Can anyone help with what it would to export it and then upload it. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the items that are the issue, it's actually the order that isn't stored.

The menu order is stored in the **wp_posts** table, under the **menu_order** field. This field isn't currently included in the WordPress XML Import/Export. There's a trouble ticket in the Trac project with a temporary patch to fix this if you need this immediately, I would suspect that this will be included in the next release:

- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/4024
- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/4024/wp-export-import.diff

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

For a recent build I was forced to manually migrate the :

- wp_terms
- wp_term_taxonomy
- wp_term_relationships

doing this manually perfectly copied my menu's to the new site.

Answer (score 0):

Menu settings are stored in the options table. Dump that table and take a look at how they are structured.

Comment: By menus I mean the Appearance > Menus in WordPress 3.0

Comment: But Menus are custom post types and would be stored in the posts table would they not?

Comment: Just checked in wp_posts table and the nav menu items are defo in this table and NOT in the wp_options table.